# Using QGIS Queries With ArcGIS Server FeatureServer

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, query, json, feature-service

I am trying to load USGS Transportation Vector Data from the US National Map data set.

REST Link: https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/transportation/MapServer

If I use the feature server I am able to load layers

[image]

However, clicking "Build Query" throws the following error

`Protocol "" is unknown`

Presuming that this feature is functional for other users, I am wondering what I am doing wrong to be able to build queries for this Feature Server?

---

There are two things that tell me this should be possible and I am missing some URL construction.

1. I can do explicit queries as JSON vector layers
2. Checking the box "Only request features overlapping the current view" works as intended. The mechanism by which it works is through a query...

I have tried adding `?query&f=pjson` and a few other combinations of urls that worked as explicit layers.

This is a very large dataset so must be queried, there are many of them so I would prefer the convenience of the FeatureServer layer dialog. Without query there is no way for me to load some of the more detailed layers.

The feature server advertises as queryable

`"capabilities": "Data,Map,Query"`